# Determine the xpath of the common ID used having different title

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, dhtml

I am trying to get the right xpath of the element which has a same ID like other elements has on the same page but it has a different title tagged to it.

Example:

```
<a class="gwt-Anchor" id="CATALOG_ITEM_HEADER" href="javascript:;" title="Linux-Sandbox">Linux-Sandbox</a>
```

here if you see in the example id="CATALOG_ITEM_HEADER" is being used commonly on the same page for other elements as well but the only thing unique which help to determine the right xpath is the title="Linux-Sandbox">Linux-Sandbox

Pls suggest me how to get to the xpath if someone has done that at their side

Comment: <a class="gwt-Anchor" id="CATALOG_ITEM_HEADER" href="javascript:;" title="Linux-Sandbox">Linux-Sandbox</a>  This is the example

Comment: Just an observation: Having the same `id` multiple times on one page is generally a defect.

Answer (score 0):

For the first link use this :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Linux-Sandbox')])[1]")).getText()
```

OR use `//*[@id="CATALOG_ITEM_HEADER"][1]` as xpath

for second :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Linux-Sandbox')])[2]")).getText()
```

OR use `//*[@id="CATALOG_ITEM_HEADER"][2]` as xpath
so on ..

The index will keep incrementing as ur `<a>` repeats with same `id`

Answer (score 0):

To get the link with an XPath :

```
//a[@id='CATALOG_ITEM_HEADER'][@title='Linux-Sandbox']
```

And with a CSS selector:

```
a[id='CATALOG_ITEM_HEADER'][title='Linux-Sandbox']
```